rsync not working: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [Receiver=FW_5.27.105-149-gbfc7d29a]
I have a Synology NAS running DSM and I'm trying to use Hyperbackup (a Synology DSM backup tool) to backup some files to my WD My Cloud EX2 NAS on the same network, the only way they can communicate is with rsync given hyperbackup is very limited in ways you can locally backup and WD abandoned My Cloud a long time ago and it doesn't have many functions left, so rsync is the only communication they have in common.
I connected via SSH to my WD My Cloud to set up rsync, I ran the daemon, created the target folder, created the rsyncd.conf and .secrets files like this:
[vault]
path = /shares/vault
comment = Vault directory for backups
read only = false
uid = root
gid = root
auth users = backupuser
secrets file = /opt/etc/rsyncd.secrets

backupuser:my_password

Everything seams to be configured correctly, but in my Synology NAS when I input the information to connect to the WD My Cloud it gives a connection error, which is weird because I know they can connect, before Synology gives me that error it lists the "Vault" folder from my WD, so it's actually connecting and retrieving data from it, it knows the name of the folder I configured in the rsync, but when I click next it gives me this fail to connect error. 
Trying to troubleshoot I used rsync rsync://backupuser@localhost:873/vault to check if the problem was the connection between the two NAS' or if it is the rsync running on my WD, and the result is:
root@Cerqueira-Vault log # rsync rsync://backupuser@localhost:873/vault
Password: 
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [Receiver=FW_5.27.105-149-gbfc7d29a]

So it seems that not even locally I can connect, so the problem must be the rsync in the WD, I already reset it to factory settings and tried again but with no success, I encounter the same error and I have no idea how to fix it, I dont know what is wrong, I follow all the instructions and im at a lost, did I configure something wrong? Is it the version of rsync in my WD broken? Does anyone know how to fix this error?

You might get some debug output if you add option -vv to your local rsync test.
